# jquery animate with center responsive

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

I'm trying to animate a box to the center of the screen's width using jquery with .css that will respond to browser size adjustment but I can't seem to get it to respond right in the center without refreshing the browser. Here's the code:

```
<div class="box"></div>

.box {
    position: absolute;
    border: 1px solid red;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
}

$(function(){
    $(".box").css({left: $(window).width() / 2 - $(".box").width() / 2})
    .animate({left: '-=0%', top: '100px'},700);
});
```

I tried using `.css({left:'50%'})` that will respond to browser size but now the box is not centered.

Comment: I am trying to understand what you are trying to do, bear with me. So you want to *center* the **box** *horizontally* to begin with, and then you want to animate this **box** *vertically* only right after, no horizontal motion? And then your *resize* events should not animate the **box** at all such that your **box** should remain centred *horizontally* respective to current browser resized state but without any animation and *vertically* where you had animated it to be previously? Is this correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on my understanding of your problem as I mentioned in comments, this is a solution that you can use.

```
$(function(){
  $(".box").css({left:'50%',transform:'translateX(-50%)'}).animate({top:'100px'},700);
});
```

Reference: [Centering Percentage Width/Height Elements](https://css-tricks.com/centering-percentage-widthheight-elements/).

Comment: yes this is exactly what i'm trying to do. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can center by using this css example:
http://www.thesitewizard.com/css/center-div-block.shtml

code snippet:

```
#box{
      ...
      margin-left: auto ;
      margin-right: auto ;
    }
```

As you're using box. I believe you want something like a modal window. So, you can use jquery UI for that:
https://jqueryui.com/dialog/

Answer (score 0):

If you still need style using jQuery you can try use left again `.css({left:'50%'})` then add negative margin left 50% of box `.css({marginLeft: ($('.box').width() / 2)*-1})`

so summary of animated code

```
$(".box").css({left: $(window).width() / 2 - $(".box").width() / 2})
.animate({left: '50%', marginLeft:  ($(".box").width()/2)*-1, top: '100px'},700);
```